# advanced filter for omitting parameters value

Tags: google-analytics

I want to omit value of selected parameters in analytics reports.

For example in urls there is `domain/param1=1234` and I want to see in reports `domain/param1`.

I can achieve this goal by using advanced filter but I don't have idea about `regexp` which should be used.

Comment: Technically speaking  domain/param1=1234 is not a parameter, it's a path (no question mark or other delimiters). Is this intended or is there a typo ?

Comment: only typo. I want to see domain?param1=1234 as domain?param1

Comment: I found solution. I used search and replace filter. Advanced filter is not solution for this problem. I used Search and replace -> Request url -> Search: parameter_to_omit\=[a-z0-9]{1,35}$ and Replace: omited_string. Now in raports I can see only omited_string.